# What is the maximum possible value of nonce

Tags: mining-technical-details, technical-details

What is the maximum possible value of nonce and the maximum possible size of nonce in randomx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are (at least) 2 places a nonce can be used in the data (the block hashing blob) being hashed in Monero:

1. in the block header, the nonce field, which is a 32 bit unsigned int, so a maximum value of 0xffffffff.
2. in the coinbase tx extra field (which is however many bytes the miner has reserved).

Comment: I was asking about the maximum possible value and size of nonce when we are mining and changing the value of hash

Comment: As answered. The block header nonce (1) 0xffffffff and the coinbase "nonce" (2) depends on how much space was reserved by the miner.

Comment: can you explain

Comment: "can you explain", I thought I had in the answer. What specifically do you need more explanation on?

Comment: both the points

Comment: "0xffffffff" is 4294967295 (in decimal) and "however many bytes the miner has reserved" is as it says. For common pool mining, the usable nonce space is again 0xffffffff, but again this is defined by pool and miner implementations, because the coinbase tx can use however many bytes they reserve.

Comment: thanks for help